# Unable to preventDefault inside passive Konva event listener due to target being treated as passive

Tags: javascript, dom-events, konvajs

I'm using the [Konva.js@1.3.0](https://konvajs.github.io/) library (with React@15.4.2 and [`react-konva`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-konva@1.1.1)) to build a simple 2D game.

When testing the app in Chrome all is well. However, when I open Dev Tools and switch to the Device Toolbar (to view the app on mobile-sized viewports) I get an warning of:

> Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.
>       See http‍s://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080

I've read through the link and researched the `{passive: true}` option for `AddEventListener`. However, I'm not directly calling `AddEventListener` in my code, it's all abstracted through Konva and React.

Also, none of the click events attached to the Konva-generated canvas elements are working in Device Mode. If I exit the Device Toolbar everything works fine and clicking elements functions as intended.

How can I enable passive event listeners in Konva/React? (And is that even the solution?)

Comment: I am not sure where these errors are come from.
But to enable touch event support you need to add touch listeners in your code. E.g. add "onClick" and "onTap".

Comment: I was using `onClick` previously. Should I replace those (or add) `onTap`? Does that require the Tappable package?

Comment: You don't need any other packages. You just need to add more listeners (touch events and mouse events are the different events in Konva).

Comment: I naively replaced an `onClick` with `onTap` and everything started working with no errors. I'm not requiring any package that handles `onTap` so I'm  confused how that's even working.

Comment: You can read more about events in Konva here http://konvajs.github.io/docs/events/Desktop_and_Mobile.html (and in other related "events" tutorials). List of ALL events you can read here: http://konvajs.github.io/api/Konva.Shape.html#on

Answer (score 1):

I had got the same error browser console, I had referred link: https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula/issues/468
and update `touch-action` CSS property, It works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble, this is a breaking change in Chrome 56 to [improve scroll performance](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/01/scrolling-intervention).  You probably need to add an appropriate `touch-action` [CSS rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action) to explicitly disable touch scrolling.

Comment: add to where or which element?